# iOS Spring board like Grid View with dragging & moving items + delete option in iOS 5

Tags: gridview, ios5, draggable, long-press

I want to implement iOS spring board like functionality in my app. I want to display images in grid fashion. Images can be draggable so that I can change the position of image.  Long press will animate image same as while deleting app from springboard. Does anybody know about any control available? I saw GMGridView. Is there any alternative to GMGridView provided it supports all the functionalities mentioned above? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GMGridView but you need to modify it to display the delete icons while moving the cells.

1. Import GMGridViewCell+Extended.h
2. In GMGridView's delegate method "did start moving cell", add this line:

   [cell setEditing:YES animated:YES];

NOTE:- You may need to call this line for each and every cell of GMGridView.